# Knapsack algorithm with combinations of items

Tags: algorithm, knapsack-problem

I've got a problem which I think is a variation of the knapsack problem. Basically I have a set  A of size s, from which I have to select the best combination of groups of size n. The order of the items within a group doesn't matter. Equally, the order of the groups doesn't matter either.

So these two sets of groups would be considered equivalent:

```
{ a, b }, { a, c }
{ c, a }, { a, b }
```

So for instance a set A = { a, a, b, b, c } and n = 2 would give these combinations:

```
{ a, a }, { b, b }
{ a, a }, { b, c }
{ a, b }, { a, b }
{ a, b }, { a, c }
{ a, c }, { b, b }
```

From these groups I'd select the ones with the best value. I've been taking a bit of a brute-force approach to the problem, but I'm running into performance problems rather quickly. My strategy basically consists of these steps:

1. Create all permutations of the set.
2. For each permutation, split the set in groups of size n.
3. Remove all "duplicate" sets of groups (i.e. { a, b } = { b, a })
4. Calculate the value for each set of groups and select the one with the highest value.

For a set of 5 or 6 items that's quite ok, the number of permutations is still quite manageable. After that, things just get out of hand, with the number of permutations being s!.

I could use some pointers on how to approach this problem in a more efficient way.

Comment: How are you computing the value of a group?  If it is the sum, then why not just use the biggest elements in your set?

Comment: I've got a few different functions that compute the value of a group, like max, min and avg. The value of a set of groups is the sum of the values of the individual groups.